# Display Html string properly in mvc.net view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I pass Html-string like

```
<div style="color:red;">Hello</div>
```

to model and display it like

```
<section>
 @foreach(var item in Model) { @Html.Raw(@item.HTMLText)}
 </section>
```

But I give the HTML-string itself, not red text.
What can be wrong?

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the `@` for `@item`, just have `@Html.Raw(item.HTMLText)`.  If you remove that, does that help?

Comment: And you put a breakpoint on this line and verified the HTML is what you expected?  Also view source in the browser to see if it's rendering the way you expect.  I've had that issue before.  Outside of that, I don't know what it could possibly be.

Comment: It works fine for me as well. Could you demostrate your code, when passing that string to you model?

Comment: @OlegSafarov
"<p>&lt;div style=&quot;color:red&quot;&gt;Hello, world&lt;/div&gt;</p>\r\n"     This is what I got from model, and what I pass

Comment: I passed the parameter this way: "<p><div style=\"color:red\">Hello, world</div></p>\r\n" and it works. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, by decoding the string I get from database, and getting rid off /r/n chars and paragraph tags.

```
 item.HTML = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item.HTML);
 item.HTML = item.HTML.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
 item.HTML = item.HTML.Substring(3, item.HTML.Length - 7);//I always get text wrapped in <p>...</p>
```